# Rules for raising Very Low Quality flag on question automatically in Help and Improvement queue

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts, help-improvement

I noticed that sometimes when I click "question is very low quality" this flag is automatically raised, but sometimes not. Suggestion is that it is raised when question has negative score, but I can't find any information about this in related questions or FAQ, so please confirm is this right.

Linked question doesn't answer mine: what is the rule when the flag is raised and when not? Okay, Martijn Pieters comment is a part of an answer, but it is not full answer right now.

Comment: It's probably related to whether or not there have already been other VLQ flags raised against the question. Downvotes don't always mean a question is VLQ.

Comment: VLQ flags *can't be raised* on a post with a positive score.